# Write the dimension of 1D wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, units, probability, dimensional-analysis

I want to know how to find the dimension or unit of one-dimensional wave function

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442485/2451

Answer (score 1):

We typically normalize wavefunctions to
$$
\int |\psi(x)|^2 \mathrm dx = 1,
$$
and integrating functions produces a result whose dimension is the product of the dimension of the integrand times the integrating variable:
$$
\left[ \int f(x) \mathrm dx\right]
= [f(x)] \times [\mathrm dx]
= [f(x)] \times [x].
$$
I'll leave it to you to put those two facts together to find $\left[|\psi|^2\right]$ and from that $\bigg[|\psi|\bigg] = \sqrt{\left[|\psi|^2\right]}$.

Comment: Nice answer. Am I mistaken, or aren't the units of the wavefunction inversely proportional to the length so that the probability itself is dimensionless?